# Salesforce mobile app appears to be a desktop version instead of mobile app version

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

Salesforce mobile app appears to be a desktop version instead of the mobile app version. This is happening for a user using the Standard User profile. Is there something that needs to be activated to get back the mobile app version? Please help me if someone has any solutions.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sam - Where are you running the app? If you are doing it on iPad, I recommend taking a look at https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesforce_app_ipad_considerations.htm&type=5 and ensure you are meeting the technical requirements outlined in this doc- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_ipad_browser.htm&type=5. Also, ensure you are using  the latest version https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesforce_app_rn_228.htm&type=5

Comment: If you are still experiencing the issue. I recommend engaging support. Salesforce Customer Support uses commercially reasonable efforts to troubleshoot issues with the Salesforce mobile app, provided:

A user’s device meets current minimum platform requirements
Users have the most recent version of Salesforce for iOS or Android installed

Answer (score 0):

The user is not logged in. You can tell because the ‘Login’ banner is still at the top. I’d make sure if they are logging in via the org’s custom url, and ensure they are following this process: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329129&type=1&mode=1&language=en_US